# Delete a line that doesn't have an specific line above it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I had this rythimn game chart script

```
TARGET(1
TIME(268466)
TARGET(1
TIME(273333)
TIME(278723)
TARGET(1
TIME(306666)
TIME(309492)
TARGET(0
TIME(330005)
```

However, I need that every line maintains a "time, target, time, target" pattern. But like you see there are times that repeat, and those times probably have to do with the timing of other objects, not these targets, which is why I need to get them out. So it should look like this:

```
TARGET(1
TIME(268466)
TARGET(1
TIME(273333)
TARGET(1
TIME(306666)
TARGET(0
TIME(330005)
```

Basically, delete the line with the word "TIME" if the line above also contains the word "TIME" (delete the second line that also contains the word TIME). How can I achieve this without removing them manually? I believe there are thousands of lines to work with.

Comment: Replace `(TIME\([0-9]+\))\r\nTIME\([0-9]+\)` with `\1`?

Comment: That does just one, bit more tinkering to do it for more

Comment: replace `(TIME\([0-9]+\))(\r\nTIME\([0-9]+\))+` with `\1`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace matches of

```
(?<=^TIME\(\d{6}\))\r?\nTIME\(\d{6}\)
```

with empty strings.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3apC1/1)

The demo uses the PCRE regex engine but I expect the results would be the same as using Notepad++'s, as the latter [does support fixed-length negative lookbehinds](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/).

Notice that at the demo I added the line `"TIME(309493)"` to illustrate that if two or more lines matching

```
^TIME/(\d{6}/)\r?\n
```

follow a line matching

```
^TARGET\(\d\r?\n
```

all but the first of those ("TIME") lines will be matched and therefore can be converted to empty strings.

I understand `\r?\n` can be replaced with `\R`.

Comment: Notepad++ has `\R` to match any newline sequence, see the [Notepad++ user manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#special-control-escapes). So the `\r?\n` can be simplified to `\R`.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Notepad++, you might use:

```
^TIME\(\d+\)\K(?:\RTIME\(\d+\))+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `TIME\(\d+\)` Match TIME and 1+ digits between parenthesis (use `\d{6}` for exactly 6 digits)
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?:\RTIME\(\d+\))+` Repeat 1+ times matching a newline and the TIME pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLggnn/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

---

If the `TARGET(` part must follow, you can assert it using a positive lookahead:

```
^TIME\(\d+\)\K(?:\RTIME\(\d+\))+(?=\RTARGET\(\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKNtlj/1)